# Is there a good touch library for IE10 & other browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I really just need simple gesture detection (swipe left/right, etc) for POJ or jQuery.  For various reasons, it must run on IE10 as a first-class citizen, but none of the libraries I've seen have good support for this detection.

I was hoping for a nice, tested, all-inclusive solution.

Have I missed something, or do I need to start said project?

Comment: Can somebody please fill me on on the downvotes?  If I've asked my question incorrectly or in the wrong place, I'm happy to alter.  At this point, my only expectation is that people hate IE, and while I am not necessarily a fan, that doesn't change my project requirements.

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*" is why the close votes are there, not sure on downvotes though other than the question is not useful.

Comment: @KevinB I hear you, but I think there was much value here.  I found several other people with the same issues asking the same question, with no answer... and only re-asked because of the staleness of said question.  In the end, I was pointed at a new library which I had not yet tried (as in, no go on TouchSwipe, Deep Tissue, and a host of others I can't even remember)... but that library solved my issue and hopefully this post will help others in the future.  I wasn't looking for the 'best tool for X', I was looking for 'ANY tool for X', which seems to be a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE10 has built-in utilities for detecting high-level browser gestures. If you are coding primarily for IE10, you'll be able to create the best user experience using its built-in library, which is called [MSGesture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh968035.aspx).

As you can infer from its name, however, MSGesture is IE-only. If you have to support other browsers, you might try [Hammer.JS](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/).

Comment: Thanks much, that totally did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Hammer.js has good support for cross-browser multi-touch support and there are work arounds for the particular issues in I.E. you can get it from github here:

https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js

I have had some issue with IE 10 firing a click event as well with touch gestures and it is covered on the Github wiki here:

https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/issues/308

Hope that helps!